# Angularjs CSS animation not working with ng-show

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-show

I am loading an array of JSON objects with an image, some text, and an index (0 through 3) into a slider using ng-repeat. I have functions that change which image and text display based on navigation buttons clicked that correspond with each JSON object. I've been able to get the correct image and text to appear in the slider, however, the CSS animation is not working. Does anyone know what's wrong with my code? Thanks.

```
          <div class="slide-window"  >

                 <div ng-repeat="x in content" class="slide" ng-show="showSlide == {{x.index}}" >


                            <img src="{{x.image}}" />
                            <div class="slide-copy">{{x.copy}}</div>  


                </div>



.slide.ng-enter, .slide.ng-leave {

 -webkit-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
  -moz-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
  -o-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s;
  transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 0.5s; 

}

.slide.ng-enter {

position:absolute;
 left:100%;

}

.slide.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
left:0; 

}

.slide.ng-leave {

  position:absolute;
  left:0;
}

.slide.ng-leave-active {

      left:-100%;
}
```

Comment: Did you include `ngAnimate` as a module?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your ng-show expression `showSlide == {{x.index}}` is a wrong syntax. What you want instead is `showSlide === x.index`

Then, the `ng-enter` and `ng-leave` class are for animating elements that are added/removed from the DOM, either because you updated an array within a `ng-repeat`, or because they have been modified by a `ng-if`.

The ngShow directive doesn't remove anything from the DOM, but simply add a specific class that hides the element (using the `display: none` styling).

The correct way to animate such directive is by using the `.ng-show` and `.ng-hide` class, as you can read in the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow